# In MS Word how do I convert a Set Field containing "$1540.38-" to a negitive number I can sum

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that has fields set by our main publishing software. This software cannot utilize VBA code.

The fields I have to sum are things like

```
{SET ArrearsBalance "$1,540.38-"}, 
{SET RepossessionCosts "$200.00"},
 and {SET StorageCost "$200.00"}
```

If I have them in a table and then use `{=SUM(A1,A2,A3)}` it will give a total of $400

If I manually remove the trailing - I can get the total as if they were all positive.

If I manually remove the - from the back of the number and put it at the front it will sum correctly.

Is there a way trim/move the - symbol to the front of the $ symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Comments consolidated/augmented into an Answer

First, be warned: the way that Word interprets currency strings is dependent on the regional settings for the computer displaying the document. e.g. on a machine with typical US settings, "$1,540.38" will be recognised as a number, but "£1,540.38" will not.

There are other potential problems in this area, which lead me to suggest that you do something like this for each amount that you want to sum:

```
{ SET XArrearsBalance "{ IF "{ ArrearsBalance }" = "*-" "-" }{ ={ ArrearsBalance }-0 }" }
```

(All the {} need to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows Word using ctrl-F9.

If you just have an amount with the wrong format in cell A1, you cannot easily  strip the trailing "-" in the same way because the "=" field can only work with numbers - you can't get it to manipulate texts. So you probably need to put that whole formula in cell A1.

Once you have done that, your formula needs to be

```
{ =SUM(XArrearsBalance,XRepossessionCosts,XStorageCost) }
```

If you do have literal values in your cells, another way you can reference the values is to create a different paragraph style for each cell you want to reference. Let's say you create a style called "SArrearsBalance" and apply it to cell A1. Then you should be able to use

```
{ STYLEREF SArrearsBalance }
```

to get the value of the cell, and you can (probably) use

```
{ IF "{ STYLEREF SArrearsBalance }" = "*-" "-" }{ ={ STYLEREF SArrearsBalance }-0 }" }
```

Some say that you can bookmark the whole cell, and reference it using { REF theBookmarkName } but I usually find that this leads to large, incorrect numbers being generated by calculations.